# Compare strings with unicode characters in python

Tags: python, unicode

Here is the substring `Ritē`

I have two strings, one is from the extracted file name by `zipfile`. I used `filename.encode('cp437').decode('utf-8')` to have all the paths extracted correctly. The other one is read from a `.plist` using `plistlib.readPlist()`. Both are printed correctly using `print()`. However, they are not the same in comparison. I tried to encode both of them in `utf-8`, here is what they look like:

- `Rite\xcc\x84`
- `Rit\xc4\x93`

  One interprets character e and - on top, the other one interprets the ['LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH MACRON'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0113/index.htm)
  Does any one have any advice on this, in order to compare the two strings? Thank you in advance

Comment: This comment isn't entirely clear.  What do you want to happen?  If two strings are different, then they'll compare as unequal in python.

Comment: I mean two strings are the same, but they were encoded differently (one by the zipfile and the other one by the plistlib). My goal is to be able to match the two.

Comment: can you please provide links to original data files? Assuming you're seeing them both as Ritē, those unicode translations are not correct which means you are using the wrong encoding to read them somewhere -- I suspect the issue is in your .encode('cp437')

Comment: You want to use the `unicodedata` built-in module to convert both to a common representation.

Comment: If I don't use 'cp437', it will be like this: Rite╠ä or in utf-8: Rite\xe2\x95\xa0\xc3\xa4

Comment: see [When "Zoë" !== "Zoë". Or why you need to normalize Unicode strings](https://withblue.ink/2019/03/11/why-you-need-to-normalize-unicode-strings.html), [How Twitter normalize strings](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/counting-characters)

Comment: yes yours is also helpful! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments it sounds like this is what you're looking for:

```py
import unicodedata

foo = 'Rit\u0113'
bar = 'Rite\u0304'

print(foo, bar)

print(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', foo))
print(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', bar))

assert unicodedata.normalize('NFD', foo) == unicodedata.normalize('NFD', bar)
```

I selected NFD as the form, but you may prefer [NFC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize).

Comment: Thanks very much. That works like a charm